# Maximizing objective function with non-concave constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have a maximization problem in the form 
$$\max_{x} ~f(x)= \max_{x}~a ~\log(1+x) - b ~x \\
y ~x - c ~z ~ \log(1+x) \leq 0\\
a,b,c,x,y,z >0
$$

I computed the Hessian of the function $z ~ \log(1+x)$ and I found all the principal minors are negative.
Can I use KKT conditions to solve or not?

Comment: the variables are x, y and z

Comment: sorry the optimization variable is x. The original problem I am trying to solve contains more constraints, all of them convex except the one I an describing here.

Comment: Please write your optimization problem in a standard form. Unknowns should be denoted using the last letters of the alphabet. Knowns should be denoted using the first letters of the alphabet. This is a useful convention and I don't see why you deviate from it.

Comment: I am using the standard form. The unknowns  are x, y and z. The knowns are a, b and c. The question is what kind of solutions I can use when the hessian matrix is indefinite. I found some works dedicated to linear problems and quadratic problems but not applicable to my formulated problem.